# Python Lxml: Adding and deleting tags

Tags: python, parsing, exception, lxml

I am attempting to add and remove tags in an xml tree (snip below). I have a dict of boolean values that I use to determine whether to add or remove a tag. If the value is true, and the element does not exist, it creates the tag (and its parent if it doesn't exist). If false, it deletes the value.

However, it doesn't seem to work, and I can't find out why.

```
<Assets>
  <asset name="Adham">
    <pos>
      <x>27913.769923</x>
      <y>5174.627773</y>
    </pos>
    <GFX>
      <space>P03.png</space>
      <exterior>snow.png</exterior>
    </GFX>
    <presence>
      <faction>Dvaered</faction>
      <value>10.000000</value>
      <range>1</range>
    </presence>
    <general>
      <class>P</class>
      <population>100</population>
      <services>
        <land/>
        <refuel/>
      </services>
      <commodities/>
      <description>Fooo</description>
      <bar>(null)</bar>
    </general>
  </asset>
</Assets>
```

Code:

```
def writeflagX(self, root, x_path, _flag): 
    ''' Writes flag to tree: deletes if false and already exists
    and adds if true but doesn't exist yet)
    '''
    try:
        if root.xpath(x_path):
            if not self.flag[_flag]: 
                #delete value
                temp1 = root.xpath(x_path)
                temp1.getparent().remove(temp1)
                print "removed"
                #yeah, pretty ugly
    except AttributeError:
        #element does not exist, so create it if true value is here
        #first, see if parent tag of list items exists, create it if neccesary
        #split xpath into leader and item
        leader = x_path.split("/")[0]
        print leader
        item = x_path.split("/")[1]
        try:
            if root.xpath(leader): #try to see if parent tag exists
                child = etree.Subelement(root.xpath(leader), item)
                print "no errors"
            print "not caught"
        except AttributeError:
            l2 = leader.split("/")[0]
            print l2 + " hi"
            try:
                l3 = leader.split("/")[1]
                if  l3: #if this tag is not a direct child of the root 
                    child1 = etree.Subelement(root.xpath(l2), l3)
                    child1.append(etree.Element(item))
                    print "no dex error"
            except IndexError: #if this tag is a direct child of the root
                print "dex error"
                child2 = etree.SubElement(root, l2)

def writeALLflagsX(self, _root):
    '''Uses writeflagX and sets all the flags
    '''
    for k in self.flag:
        self.writeflagX(_root, self.flagPaths[k], k)
```

I try to change the mission flag from false to true, and the refuel flag from true to false.

```
#Change Missions to true and refuel to false

foo = Asset()
###parsing code###
foo.alist["Adham"].flag["Is_missions"] = True
foo.alist["Adham"].flag["Is_refuel"] = False
foo.alist["Adham"].writeALLflagsX(foo.alist["Adham"].node)

foo.writeXML("output.xml")
```

I am stumped. The missions tag does not get added and the refuel tag does not get deleted.

Does this have something to do with me nesting the try/except statements?

Edit:
Ok, fixed the deleting problem by using a for loop as suggested:

```
temp1 = root.xpath(x_path)
                    for n in temp1:
                        n.getparent().remove(n)
```

Still can't add a node.

I think I am going to set up a new question that is simpler, since this is too convoluted.

Edit edit: new question that is much better: [How to handle adding elements and their parents using xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5547589/289380)

Comment: What does not work exactly? Please bring it down to a reasonable reproducable testcase instead of providing page long unrelated code.

Comment: I will reorganize the code snippets.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things could be improved in the code:

- `node.xpath` returns the list of nodes - i.e. you can't do `root.xpath(path).getparent()`, check the list and take the node #0 if you're sure that it should exist (you node deletion code uses this);
- when working with attributes try using `node.attrib` dictionary. Working with attributes becomes as easy as modifying python dictionary (`del node.attrib[attr]` and `node.attrib[attr] = value`, make sure the `value` is `str` though);
- it might be useful to use `etree.XML('<myelement><child/></myelement>')` for creating new nodes.

Hope it helps.

Comment: How do I delete a node referred to by an xpath if I don't use getparent()? Also, the reason I have functions to do the writing to the attributes is that I have a very long list of variables to pull from this file (and several kinds of files). I have abstracted out the checking process so I don't have to repeat my code for each type of file.

Comment: You certainly use `getparent()`, but do it like this: `nodes = node.xpath(xpath); for n in nodes: n.getparent().remove(n)`

Comment: Ok, that fixed the deleting problem.