# How to handle adding elements and their parents using xpath

Tags: python, xpath, addition, lxml

Ok, I have a case where I need to add a tag to a certain other tag given an xpath.

Example xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Assets>
 <asset name="Adham">
  <general>>
   <services>
    <land/>
    <refuel/>
   </services>
  </general>
 </asset>
 <asset name="Test">
  <general>
   <Something/>
  </general>
 </asset>
</Assets>
```

I want to add a `<missions>` tag to both assets. However, the second asset is missing the parent `<services>` tag, which I want to add. Each asset tag is stored in a variable (say node1, node2).

I have the following xpath: `xpath1 = services/missions`, which, due to the way my program works, I cannot simply store in a different form (i.e. i don't have a place to store just `services`)

I need to check and see if the missions tag already exists, and, if so, do nothing. If the tag does not exist, I need to create it. If its parent does not exist, I need to create that too.

How can I do this simply by using the xpath string?

Edit: I want to base all this on a boolean value: i.e. val = true, then create tag (and parent) if neccesary. If false, then delete tag.

(I have no other way of referring to the tag I need (since I have layers on layers of functions to automate this process on a large scale, you can check out my previous question here [Python Lxml: Adding and deleting tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5547257/289380))).

Edit edit: Another issue:

I don't have a variable containing the parent of the element to add, just a variable containing the `<asset>` object. I am trying to get the parent of the node I want using the xpath and a variable pointing to the ` tag.

Edit edit edit: Never mind the above, I will fix the issue by shorting the xpath to point to the parent, and using a variable name to refer to each item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def to_xml(parent, xpath, value):
    """
    parent: lxml.etree.Element
    xpath: string like 'x/y/z', anything more complex is likely to break
    value: anything, if is False - means delete node
    """        
    # find the node to proceed further        
    nodes = parent.xpath(xpath)        
    if nodes:
        node = nodes[0]
    else:
        parts = xpath.split('/')
        p = parent
        for part in parts:
            nodes = p.xpath(part)
            if not nodes:
                n = etree.XML("<%s/>" % part)
                p.append(n)
                p = n
            else:
                p = nodes[0]
        node = p
    # do whatever is specified vy value
    if value is False:
        node.getparent().remove(node)
    else:
        node.text = str(value)
```

Although I'm not sure that combining add & remove functionality in 1 function is good idea, but anyway this is likely to work as you're expecting.

Comment: Looks like this will work, but I updated to question to include deleting as well (after you posted). Could you give me the option to delete a tag if a pass a false value?

Comment: Sure, but what is the logic of the deletion, say you specified `'x/y/z', false`. What does that mean - delete node: `z` or `x` ?

Comment: It would mean delete z (the 'bottom-most' node).

Comment: @Biosci3c - I've updated the code, please check if that helps

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it when I get the chance. I know what you mean about having add/delete functionality in the same function, but I can't think of another way to do it within the scheme of my project, as I need to call this code as a function and have it handle either case.